# Help proving Cantor Intersection Theorem using Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, self-learning

Came across the following exercise in *Bartle*'s *Elements of Real Analysis* and am quite unsure about my solution. Would greatly appreciate it if someone could take a look at it. The Bolzano - Weierstrass as mentioned in the text is "Every bounded infinite subset of $\Bbb R^p$ has a cluster point".

> Prove the [Cantor Intersection Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CantorsIntersectionTheorem.html) by selecting a point $x_n$
>   from $C_n$ and then applying the Bolzano - Weierstrass Theorem to the
>   set $\{x_n \ | \ n \in \Bbb N \}$.

**My Attempt:**

Let $C_1 \supset C_2 \supset \  ... \ \supset C_n \supset \ ... $ be a sequence of non-void compact sets in $\Bbb R^p$. Without loss of generality we may assume that each set in the sequence is a "proper" subset of its predecessor. Then we can choose $x_n \in C_n \setminus C_{n + 1}$for every $n \in \Bbb N$. Then the set $ A = \{x_n \ | \ n \in \Bbb N \}$ will have infinitely many elements. $A$ is bounded since $A \subseteq C_1 $. Therefore by the Bolzano - Weierstrass Theorem $\exists x_j \in A$ such that every neighbourhood of $x_j$ contains at least one element in $A$ distinct from $x_j$.

Suppose $x_j \not \in C_n$ for certain $n \in \Bbb N$. Let $m = \text{Min} \{n \in \Bbb N \ | \ x_j \not \in C_n\}$. $m$ exists by the Well-Ordering Principle. Then $x_j \in (C_m)^C$. $ \ j \le m$ would lead to a contradiction since it would imply $x_j \in C_j \subset C_m.$ And $j \lt m - 1 \implies x_j \not \in C_{m - 1}$ again leading to a contradiction. $\therefore j = m - 1 \; (m \neq 1)$.

$(C_m)^C$ is a neighbourhood of the cluster point $x_j$ and hence $\exists x_i \in A$ such that $x_i \in (C_m)^C$. Clearly $i \lt m - 1$. Therefore the set $B = \{ x_i \ | \ x_i \in A \cap (C_m)^C \}$ is finite. Let $r = \text{Min} \{ r_i \ | \ r_i = \left| \left|{x_j - x_i}\right| \right|, x_i \in B \}$. The set $\{ y \in \Bbb R^p \ | \ \left| \left|{x_j - y}\right| \right| \lt r  \} \cap (C_m)^C$ is a neighbourhood of $x_j$ (since it is the intersection of two open sets) and contains no points in $A$ distinct from $x_j$ leading to a contradiction.

$\implies x_j \in C_n \; \forall n \in \Bbb N$

Q.E.D.

$Q_1:$ Is my restriction to consider only proper subsets fair enough? My argument is given any sequence of nested compact sets we remove the additional equal ones in the sequence and find a common point. Then it will be a common point to the original sequence too. But I need the set $\{x_n\}$ to be infinite. Will that be affected?

$Q_2:$ Is my proof correct in general? Are the arguments good enough?

Please comment. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a first thought (I haven't digested the whole proof yet): Bolzano-Weierstrass doesn't guarantee an $x_j \in A$ which is a cluster point of $A$, but rather, gives some $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$ which is a cluster point of $A$.  This also means your second paragraph is now irrelevant.  Assuming you've already proven that compact sets are closed, that that closed sets contain their limit points, you can use the two facts to argue that $x\in C_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: You do not need to consider proper subsets, $x_n\in C_n$ is enough, avoiding $C_{n+1}$ is not necessary. And why do you want to turn the constructed sequence into a set? Bolzano-Weierstraß is about sequences in compact sets.

Comment: @Jason DeVito: I had completely misunderstood the Theorem. Just read through it again. I think I have an alternate argument.  I'll post it as an answer. And yes I have already proven Heine-Borel Theorem. .

Comment: @LutzL: The book I'm reading asserts the Theorem well before introducing sequences and is described purely in topological/set theoretic language. And hence I need $\{x_n\}$ to be infinite - a construction I failed to come up with if I chose points in $C_n$ arbtrarily

Comment: How does it then come that you can work with sequences of nested subsets $C_n$? And construct the sequence elements $x_n$? Seems inconsistent. Perhaps you should document that restriction in your question, and also the formulation of Bolzano-Weierstraß that is used in the book.

Comment: @LutzL: The Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem is purely introduced in the language of neighbourhoods. A limit point $x$ of a set $A$ is according to the book, "a point such that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $A$ distinct from it". Yes, I am working with a sequence of sets. But the development so far has stayed clear of the terms, "subsequence" and "convergence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the glaring error pointed out by @Jason DeVito I'm gonna post here a corrected answer to the above exercise. Still needs some verification though I think and would love some opinion on it.

... Continuing after paragraph 1 above in my solution.

Let $x$ be the cluster point of $A$ guaranteed by the Bolzano - Weierstrass Theorem.

Suppose $x$ is an exterior point for a set $C_m$ in the sequence. Then there is a neighbourhood of $x$ entirely contained in $(C_m)^C$. This neighbourhood must contain some $x_i \in A$ such that $x_i \neq x$. Now, $i \ge m$ would lead to a contradiction since $x_i \in C_i \subset C_m$. Therefore, $i \lt m$. Let $r = \text{Min} \{ r_i \ | \ r_i = \left| \left|{x - x_i}\right| \right|, x_i \in A \cap (C_m)^C \}$. Then the set $\{ y \in \Bbb R^p \ | \ \left| \left|{x_j - y}\right| \right| \lt r  \} \cap (C_m)^C$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ and contains no elements in $A$ contradicting the fact that $x$ is a cluster point of $A$.

Therefore, $x$ is either an interior or boundary point of $C_m$. Since $C_m$ is closed it contains all of its boundary points and hence $x \in C_m$.

Since $C_m$ was arbitrary $x \in C_n \; \forall n \in \Bbb N $

Comment: I think it looks good now.

Comment: @Jason DeVito: Thanks a lot for your time. How about $Q_1$ above? Any issues?

Comment: I think Q1 is fine:  By discarding and renumbering, you can definitely assume that the $C_i$ form a strictly decreasing chain of subsets.  Note that it's possible that after discarding duplicates, only finitely many $C_i$ remain, so it's possible that you won't be able to use the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.  On the other hand, when there are only finitely many $C_i$, the theorem is trivial anyway.  One way to avoid all of this is just just take $x_i\in C_i$ without worrying if $C_{i+1}\subsetneq C_i$ or not.  Letting $A = \{x_i\}$, either $A$ is infinite (and your argument works just fine)...

Comment: or $A$ is finite.  If $A$ is finite, then the $x_j$ of largest index in $A$ will be in all the $C_i$.

Comment: @Jason DeVito: If it's not too much to ask I would love another explanation on this. Yes the case when $A$ might be finite was my problem. So, say we pick $x_i$ from $C_i$ arbitrarily. What if $A$ is finite because for the remaining larger indexes $x_i$ equals elements in the set $A$ in rotation. say after the largest index $x_j$; $x_{j + 1} = x_1, x_{j + 2} = x_2, x_{j + 3} = x_3, .., x_{2j} = x_j, x_{2j + 1 } = x_1.. $ and so forth. I can't still say that $x_j$ is the common point still can I?

Comment: I believe that any $x_j$ which is repeated infinitely will work.   If $A$ is finite, some $x\in A$ is repeated infinitely many times via your choices.  Now, given any $C_i$, because $x$ is repeated infinitely, there is a $j > i$ with $x = x_j$.  Then $x = x_j \in C_j \subseteq C_i$, so $x\in C_i$ as well.